# MYSQL Adding plus one in loop or for each

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next quarry:

```
    UPDATE PREDMETIF t
CROSS JOIN (select COALESCE(MAX(predf_aa),0) max_predf_aa from PREDMETIF) m
set t.predf_aa = m.max_predf_aa + 1
where t.strf_ID = '1';
```

Witch gives me result of:

```
| predf_aa | strp_ID | 
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1       |
| 1        | 1       | 
| null     | 2       |
```

And I need:

```
| predf_aa | strp_ID | 
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 1       |
| 2        | 1       | 
| null     | 2       |
```

I have made [Example fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dkBzmgVbBkg5unfCyT5maw/0)

I find that closest thing to for each is PROCEDURE with LOOP but never used that and it seems a bit overkill. What is simplest way to achieve this with given example?

And if [LOOP Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loop.html)  is what I need I would appreciate if someone would write it for me on this example and ill decode it for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want variables:

```
select @rn := COALESCE(MAX(predf_aa), 0) as max_predf_aa
from PREDMETIF;

update PREDMETIF t
    set t.predf_aa = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where t.strf_ID = 1;
```

That said, if you want a unique id on each row, then perhaps you want an `auto_increment` column.  Of course, you would not have `null` in that column, so it is not clear if that is a viable solution for you.